# Plotting an animated hypocycloid

Tags: geometry

I want to animate a Hypocycloid using computer code.  So far i have drawn the circles [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/circle).

I have found this definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) and I want to animate the image that is on the right.

I did something similar [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/sine) with a sine wave.  I used a counter and changed the position of the shapes using `cos` and `sin` to plot the changing shapes on each change of the counter.

This new graph is infinitely more complicated.

Wikipedia gives the following equations:

$x(\theta) = (R - r) \cos \theta + r \cos((k - 1) \theta)$

$y(\theta) = (R - r) \sin \theta - r \sin((k - 1) \theta)$

I do not know how to solve these equations.

Why is it $x(\theta) = $ and not just $x =$ ?

How do I find $\theta$ when it occurs on both sides of the equation ; besides, I do not understand what $k$ is.

Comment: What is the software you use ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I use d3.js , the source code for all the charts is here https://github.com/dagda1/d3-geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of $x(\theta)$.  The parentheses do not indicate multiplication; they instead indicate that $x$ is a **function** of the parameter $\theta$.  To plot this curve for a given $R$, $r$, and $k$, all you need to do is plug in various values of $\theta$ into each equation on the RHS, and the first equation gives you the $x$-coordinate and the second gives you the $y$-coordinate.

Comment: great, what is k in this instance.

Comment: @dagda1 $k$ is just another fixed constant, in this case the number of windings.  It is related to the symmetry of the resulting figure, so when $k = 5$ for example, you should get a figure with fivefold symmetry.